# sonar-javascript-plugin version for sonar 3.1

Tags: javascript, version, sonarqube

I am new to sonar setup. In our project we are using sonar 3.1 version. When I am trying to run the java script report, getting the following error.

> “[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project AccountBuilder: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1:sonar failed: You must
>   intall a Sonar plugin that supports language 'js' in order to analyse
>   the following project: com.directv:AccountBuilder:JavaScript -> [Help
>   1]”**

Please let know the exact sonar-javascript-plugin version for sonar 3.1?

I have seen the [following URL](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix), but the sonar 3.1 version is not present.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript Plugin 1.4 is the latest version compatible with SonarQube 3.1. Note that the plugin was much improved then (current version is 2.7) !

Comment: Thanks for the response. Plugin 1.4 version is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the release of your JavaScript plugin? 
Upgrading SonarQube version would probably solve your problem.

Comment: I tried with java scrpt plugin versions like sonar-javascript-plugin-1.4, sonar-javascript-plugin-1.6.jar, sonar-javascript-plugin-2.7.jar. Not able to get which plugin version is compatible with sonar 3.1.